# Old WSUS Server has Event ID 13032 after pointing clients to new WSUS server

Tags: windows-server-2003, wsus

We have moved to a new WSUS server and de-commissioned the old.  However, I still get the error on the old WSUS server (event logs):

> **Event ID 13032: windows server update**
>
> Many client computers have not reported back to the server in the last
>   30 days. 27 have been detected so far.
>
> For more information, see Help
>   and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

We did update GPO to point to the new server and new server is updating the workstation.

What can I do to get ride of that error?

Thanks!

Comment: Uninstall WSUS...

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you haven't uninstalled the WSUS role from the older server. If you do that, this message should go away.

If you really think about it for a second, how is the old server going to know that you've pointed the clients to a new server? It's just going to think that nothing is checking in.

Answer (score 1):

WSUS isn't fully removed and decommissioned from the old server. Once you do that, you wont get these errors.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd939818(v=ws.10).aspx